# Case Negative Column

Tags: sql, case

I have this table

| ID | TYPE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | - | 1234 |
| 2 | + | 4567 |

I want column amount to be displayed like this

| ID | TYPE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | - | -1234 |
| 2 | + | 4567 |

I tried

```
SELECT
    a.* , 
    CASE 
        WHEN a.type = '-' 
            THEN a.AMOUNT * -1 
            ELSE 'null' 
    END
FROM
    dual a
```

but it's not working because data format.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: A [`case` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) results in a _single_ data type. The rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) apply when you try to combine a numeric type (`a.AMOUNT * -1`) and a string (`'null'`). According to the rules that requires converting the string to a numeric value. What number is `'null'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would seem to want:

```
(case when a.type = '-' then - a.amount else a.amount end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option `sign()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[TYPE] varchar(50),[AMOUNT] int)  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'-',1234)
,(2,'+',456)
 
Select * 
      ,NewValue = sign(Type+'1')*Amount
 from @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
ID  TYPE    AMOUNT  NewValue
1   -       1234    -1234
2   +       456     456
```

**After thought...**

You could also use `try_convert()`

```
try_convert(int,concat(Type,Amount))  -- use desired datatype
```